# RegEx return multiple non-repeating matches

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the following pattern that matches with URLs containing long strings at the end, as commonly found in spam.  Some spam repeats the same long string so using a {4,} to detect emails with the same URL works well, but if the long string is different for each URL then it fails.  How can I extend this pattern to return "no match" unless at least 4 of this pattern are found?  I tried just copying it with a .+? in between each copy but after copying it twice regex101 starts giving errors.

```
/(?:(href|src).+?[\w\-\s]{30,}")/g
```

Demo link with better explanation: https://regex101.com/r/EOkJrS/1

Comment: Is this what you want - https://regex101.com/r/EOkJrS/2? Matches if at least four URLs (in the format you've mentioned) are present

Comment: @degant, you want the `s` modifier, not the `m`; and then you can just use `.*`.

Comment: Aah yes @trincot my bad. But wait - it actually breaks the OP's pattern (which includes a dot too) and if the `.` matches new line then the pattern doesn't work correctly.

Comment: This is really bad use of regular expressions. You should count the number of matches programmatically rather than include junk in to the match.

Comment: Jonas, I'm not doing programming here, I'm simply looking for regex patterns that my anti-spam filter can look for.  If I had a way of using my original pattern and having something say "oh, 4 matches? great, that's spam" then I'd be set, but instead I need the pattern itself to come to that conclusion and not return a match at all unless there are 4+ matches.

Comment: @degant figured it out, thank you!  The \s\S instead of . is an important difference, since email typically includes automatic line breaks that email clients ignore when looking for URLs and thus my pattern needs to work whether a line break is present or not.  I've revised your pattern to use \s\S in place of the . in my original pattern as well.  I also added a ? to make the {4,} "lazy" to reduce the number of processing steps.  [link](https://regex101.com/r/EOkJrS/4)

Comment: the /s recommendation from @trincot works in place of /gm to reduce the number of processing steps as well, so thank you too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer really belongs to @degant but I don't know how to mark his comment as an answer, plus I tweaked his answer slightly anyway....

```
/(?:(?:(href|src)[\s\S]+?[\w\-\s]{30,}")[\s\S]*?){4,}?/s
```

That's the new pattern.  It matches all URLs in HTML code (the "a href" variety and "img src" kind often used in spam emails) that contain a string of 30 or more characters which is typical of randomizers used by spambots to fool spam catchers while still being usable as email capture links.

Again thanks to both @degant and @trincot for their help!